# Core Data many-to-many predicate

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities which are related by a many-to-many relationship:

`Database <<----->> Category`

In other words, a database can have many categories and a category can be associated with many databases.

I need an `NSPredicate` that will return all Category objects associated with a given database object. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a predicate.  Given that you have a relationship called categories that is the to-many relationship to your Category entities, then

```
NSSet *categoriesForDatabase = database.categories;
```

If you really want to use a predicate then it would be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY databases = %@", database];
```

where "databases" is the name of the to many relationship on the Category entity and database is an instance of a Database entity.

Comment: I have not seen your answer before posting mine ..  sorry

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare a collection (all Category objects) to a given object, you can try something like this :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories = %@", category];
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY databases = %@", database];
```