# Core Data many-to-many predicate (again)

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

Yesterday I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155743/core-data-many-to-many-predicate) about a many-to-many relationship:

> I have two entities which are related by a many-to-many relationship:
>
> `Database <<----->> Category`
>
> In other words, a database can have many categories and a category can
>   be associated with many databases.
>
> I need an NSPredicate that will return all Category objects associated
>   with a given Database object.

...and received some very helpful advice. I would now like to ask a different, but related, question:

I would like an NSPredicate that will return all Category objects NOT associated with a given Database object.

I require this as a predicate since it is being used as part of a fetched results controller.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there scope for change the data model if you cannot solve this?

Comment: The data model itself is well-designed and makes sense, so I am hoping there is a way to address this requirement - it doesn't seem that complex in theory?

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent != %@", self.parent]; this dont work hey ??

Comment: No it doesn't, because it's a to-many relationship - not a to-one relationship: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a Core Data bug that "NOT ANY" queries do not work correctly
(see [Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722930/core-data-nspredicate-with-to-many-relationship) for a similar issue).

As a workaround, you can use the following predicate with "SUBQUERY":

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(databases, $db, $db == %@).@count == 0", theDatabase]
```

Comment: That works great. Thanks for pointing out the bug and also providing a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY databases = %@)", database];
```

Or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(%@ IN databases)", database]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - it returns nothing at all (and I know there are some categories not associated with a database that it should be returning).

Comment: Sorry to say still no go - both return no objects.